# What library is collecting advertising id for my app?

Tags: android, gradle, google-play

I recently got a google play email saying my companies app has been removed due to a lack of a privacy policy while collecting the advertising id. This app was not written by me and i am simply making some changes since i have a little of android dev experience.

here are the android app dependencies,

```
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.0'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile(
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.4.1'],
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.4.1'],
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.4.1']
)
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48'
compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
```

Which one is collecting the adverstising id, and how can I remove it with out compromising the android app's functionality?

Answer (score 2):

It is most probably Google analytics.

I also recently encountered the same problem in one of my apps and fixed it by **updating the privacy policy URL** in the Google Play console.

In the privacy policy, you need to specify clearly that you don't collect any user's data.

For now, you can take the [Privacy policy of my app](https://sites.google.com/view/offlinechatapp) as an example. It may be changed in the future though.

Comment: I had a similar issue, but I did not find the lib which causes it. But I have found a useful privacy policy generator here https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: so are you saying if i put nothing in the user information collected, and generate the privacy policy this would be sufficient to put on google play and reinstate my app?